# Storing double the user entry in a dynamic pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, cs50

I am learning pointers and doing an exercise where I'm dynamically creating a pointer and accepting input from the user and then storing the double the user entry to the dynamically created pointer in the heap and printing out the dynamically created heap to the console. The problem I am having is, it is not printing double the users entry, I have debugged it and it looks like the t variable is not saving double the user entry and i'm not sure how to resolve this.

I have posted my code below and would greatly appreciate any tips or hits that would help me solve the issue I am having.

```
The current output is: 
Say something: hey
Size of char: 8
Size of s: 8
Size of t: 8
Doubling copy...
Original: hey
Double copy: hey
Counter: 8
```

The desired output is:

```
Say something: hey
Size of char: 8
Size of s: 8
Size of t: 8
Doubling copy...
Original: hey
Double copy: heyhey (I would like this line to print double the word the user entered as input)
Counter: 8
```

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
     int scale_value = 2; 
     int counter = 0; 

    printf("Say something: "); 
    char* s = GetString();

    if (s == NULL)
    {
        return 1; 
    }

    string t = malloc((strlen(s) * scale_value + 1)* sizeof(char)); 

    if (t == NULL)
    {
        free(s);
        return 1; 
    }

    printf("Size of char: %lu\n", sizeof(char*)); 
    printf("Size of s: %lu\n", sizeof(s));
    printf("Size of t: %lu\n", sizeof(t));

    for(int j = 0; j < scale_value; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0, n = strlen(s); i<=n; i++)
        {
                t[counter] = s[i];
                counter++;
        }
    }

    printf("Doubling copy...\n"); 

    if (strlen(t)>0)
    {
        printf("Original: %s\n", s);
        printf("Double copy: %s\n", t);
        printf("Counter: %d\n", counter); 
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to include explicitly the output of the program as is, and then explicitly what lines should be different in that output. Personally, I don't know what doubling the output means.

Comment: I just updated the questions to show the current output and the output I'm trying to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you copied the terminating null-character `scale_value` times instead of once and the first terminating null-character will terminate the string. This issue will not only terminate the string too early but also cause out-of-range access (buffer overrun).

Try this instead of the copying part:

```
for(int j = 0; j < scale_value; j++)
{
    /* change <= to < to exclude the terminating null-character from what is copied */
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(s); i<n; i++)
    {
            t[counter] = s[i];
            counter++;
    }
}
/* terminate the string */
t[counter++] = '\0';
```

Also note that `%lu` is not correct format specifier to print what is returned from `sizeof`, which has type `size_t`. Using `%zu` is correct.
Using incorrect format specifier will invoke *undefined behavior*.